# Problems copying many folders

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I'm pretty new to grunt, so I need some help.

I ask this question on the official `gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy` but got no response.

I want to copy files using `grunt-contrib-copy` from some dir to another and they look like this:

```
parentpath/ (source file)
    /assets/sass/bootstrap/
    /assets/sass/fontawesome/
    /assets/sass/storms/
    /assets/sass/wordpress/
    /assets/sass/_layout.scss
    /assets/sass/_woocommerce.scss

childpath/ (destiny file)
    /assets/sass/bootstrap/
    /assets/sass/fontawesome/
    /assets/sass/storms/
    /assets/sass/wordpress/
    /assets/sass/_layout.scss
    /assets/sass/_woocommerce.scss
```

My gruntfile is configure this way:

```
copy: {
    parenttheme_bootstrap: {
        src: '<%= dirs.parentpath %>/assets/sass/bootstrap',
        dest: '<%= dirs.sass %>'
    },
    parenttheme_fontawesome: {
        src: '<%= dirs.parentpath %>/assets/sass/fontawesome',
        dest: '<%= dirs.sass %>'
    },
    parenttheme_storms: {
        src: '<%= dirs.parentpath %>/assets/sass/storms',
        dest: '<%= dirs.sass %>'
    },
    parenttheme_wordpress: {
        src: '<%= dirs.parentpath %>/assets/sass/wordpress',
        dest: '<%= dirs.sass %>'
    },
    parenttheme_partials: {
        files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= dirs.parentpath %>/assets/sass/',
                src: '_layout.scss',
                dest: '<%= dirs.sass %>'
            },
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= dirs.parentpath %>/assets/sass/',
                src: '_woocommerce.scss',
                dest: '<%= dirs.sass %>'
        }]
    }
}

// parent Task
grunt.registerTask( 'parent', [
    'copy:parenttheme_bootstrap',
    'copy:parenttheme_fontawesome',
    'copy:parenttheme_storms',
    'copy:parenttheme_wordpress',
    'copy:parenttheme_partials',
    'sass',
    'postcss'
] );
```

When I run the parent task, the /assets/sass/bootstrap folder is correctly copied to his destiny. The same goes to the partial files.

But for some reason, all the other folders are not copied and I get no errors!

Running grunt parent --verbose I get this:

```
Running tasks: parent

Running "parent" task

Running "copy:parenttheme_bootstrap" (copy) task
Verifying property copy.parenttheme_bootstrap exists in config...OK
Files: ../../childpath/assets/sass/bootstrap -> ../assets/sass
Options: encoding="utf8", processContent=false, processContentExclude=[], timestamp=false, mode=false
Creating ../assets/sass
Created 1 directory

Running "copy:parenttheme_fontawesome" (copy) task
Verifying property copy.parenttheme_fontawesome exists in config...OK
Files: ../../childpath/assets/sass/fontawesome -> ../assets/sass
Options: encoding="utf8", processContent=false, processContentExclude=[], timestamp=false, mode=false
Creating ../assets/sass
Created 1 directory

Running "copy:parenttheme_storms" (copy) task
Verifying property copy.parenttheme_storms exists in config...OK
Files: ../../childpath/assets/sass/storms -> ../assets/sass
Options: encoding="utf8", processContent=false, processContentExclude=[], timestamp=false, mode=false
Creating ../assets/sass
Created 1 directory

Running "copy:parenttheme_wordpress" (copy) task
Verifying property copy.parenttheme_wordpress exists in config...OK
Files: ../../childpath/assets/sass/wordpress -> ../assets/sass
Options: encoding="utf8", processContent=false, processContentExclude=[], timestamp=false, mode=false
Creating ../assets/sass
Created 1 directory

Running "copy:parenttheme_partials" (copy) task
Verifying property copy.parenttheme_partials exists in config...OK
Files: ../../childpath/assets/sass/_layout.scss -> ../assets/sass/_layout.scss
Files: ../../childpath/assets/sass/_woocommerce.scss -> ../assets/sass/_woocommerce.scss
Options: encoding="utf8", processContent=false, processContentExclude=[], timestamp=false, mode=false
Copying ../../childpath/assets/sass/_layout.scss -> ../assets/sass/_layout.scss
Reading ../../childpath/assets/sass/_layout.scss...OK
Writing ../assets/sass/_layout.scss...OK
Copying ../../childpath/assets/sass/_woocommerce.scss -> ../assets/sass/_woocommerce.scss
Reading ../../childpath/assets/sass/_woocommerce.scss...OK
Writing ../assets/sass/_woocommerce.scss...OK
Copied 2 files
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @James suggestion, I make this work by changing to this:

```
        sf2_bootstrap: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= dirs.sfpath %>/assets/sass/bootstrap/',
                src: '**/*.scss',
                dest: '<%= dirs.sass %>/bootstrap/'
            }]
        },
```

Now my files are correctly copied.

James solution, copied all my files, but to the wrong directory, I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to experiment with your directory and file specs a little bit.  A few things to try:

1. Add a globbing pattern to your source paths rather than just the directory name, like `.../bootstrap/**/*.scss`.
2. Add a trailing slash to the destination path so it is clearly a directory, like `dest: '<%= dirs.sass %>/'`.  It is possible that grunt is copying to a single file output, rather than a directory tree.

A small example:

```
copy: {
    parenttheme_bootstrap: {
        src: '<%= dirs.parentpath %>/assets/sass/bootstrap/**/*.scss',
        dest: '<%= dirs.sass %>/'
    },
    parenttheme_fontawesome: {
        src: '<%= dirs.parentpath %>/assets/sass/fontawesome/**/*.scss',
        dest: '<%= dirs.sass %>/'
    },
```

Comment: Hi, @James! Sry take so long to answer. I try your solution and It works! But the files were copied to `childpath/parentpath/assets/...` instead of `childpath/assets/...`. I changed just what you suggested and my defined directories are `sass: '../assets/sass'` and `parentpath: '../../parentpath'`. Any thoughts here?

Comment: That makes sense, the output paths will be relative to the **cwd** parameter.